# java: all input streams terminate with a single ctrl+z

Tags: java, io, stream

I'm working on a java exercise which needs to get customer data from input and transactions consecutively and saves them to two separate text files. while running it needs to get first file's data (oldMaster) and then gets the other one's (trans) from user input.
when I use ctrl+z to terminate first input stream the next input doesn't start to work. here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class SampleMaker {
    Formatter output1;
    Formatter output2;
    public void makeSampleOldMaster(){
        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        int accountNumber;
        double balance;

        Scanner input1=new Scanner(System.in);

        try{
         output1=new Formatter("oldmaster.txt");

         System.out.println("Enter account number,FirstName,LastName and balance");
         while(input1.hasNext()){
                accountNumber=input1.nextInt();
                firstName=input1.next();
                lastName=input1.next();
                balance=input1.nextDouble();
                output1.format("%-10d%-10s%-10s%-10.2f",accountNumber,firstName,lastName,balance);
                System.out.println("Enter account number,FirstName,LastName and balance");
            }

        }

        catch(IOException e){
            System.err.println("IO exception");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        catch(NoSuchElementException e){
            System.err.println("Invalid input");
            input1.nextLine();
        }
    }

    public void makeSampleTrans(){
        Scanner input2=new Scanner(System.in);
        double transAmount;
        int accountNumber;
        try{
        output2=new Formatter("trans.txt");
        System.out.println("Enter account number,and Transaction Amount:");
        while(input2.hasNext()){
            accountNumber=input2.nextInt();
            transAmount=input2.nextDouble();
            output2.format("%-10d%-10.2f",accountNumber,transAmount);
            System.out.println("Enter account number,and Transaction Amount:");
        }
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.err.println("IO exception");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        catch(NoSuchElementException e){
            System.err.println("Invalid input");
            input2.nextLine();
        }
    }

    public void closeOldMasterFile(){

        if(output1 != null){
            output1.close();
        }   
    }
    public void closeTransFile(){
        if(output2 != null){
            output2.close();
        }
    }
}
```

when I run this code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SampleMaker s=new SampleMaker();
        s.makeSampleOldMaster();
        s.closeOldMasterFile();
        s.makeSampleTrans();
        s.closeTransFile();

    }
}
```

after using ctrl+z to end the first input and start the second one, it stops working.

Comment: Any exceptions or normal termination?

Comment: Ctrl-Z indicates EOF (I'm assuming this is windows), so you close stdin. Wouldn't there be nothing to read from a scanner on a closed inputstream?

Answer (score 0):

End of stream is end of stream. Once `System.in` has encountered end of stream, it will deliver that to whatever you may wrap around it as many times as you do so. Your design is incorrect. You'll have to use something else to delimit the first set of input.

Comment: thanks EJP.Can you suggest any useful way to do this?